# Ajax Log Data Using HTML Button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using server side events with php and javascript to display live data on my website, this works as expected. For testing, as new transactions appear on my page I am logging the value `lastEventId`.

The `lastEventId` only contains one value, and increments with each new transaction.

I have a html button that when clicked, should also log the  value of `lastEventId`. But instead it logs multiple values, it seems to retain the previous values.

See the image below;

[image]

My desired result is, click the 'start' button once and display a single value - the most recent `lastEventId`. So, in the image above it should log;

```
The last serial received was 20543969.
```

Not the previous two.

My html page s as follows;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       var source = new EventSource("script.php");
           source.onmessage = function(event){
               document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "New transaction: " + event.data + "<br>";

           $("#start").click(function(){
               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: 'script.php',
                   data: {lastSerial: lastSerial},
                   success: function(data){
                       console.log(data);
                   }
               });
           });
      }; // end on.message
</script>
<button id="start"> start</button>
```

My PHP file;

```
if(isset($_POST['lastSerial'])) {
    $lastSerial = $_POST['lastSerial'];
    echo "The last serial received was ". $lastSerial .".";
}
```

Do I need to somehow 'reset' the value after each click?

I'm sure I am doing something very silly. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is most likely caused by same id (result), when fetching data from HTML, can you inspect your HTML?

Comment: well than do not add to the string....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With every message you are adding a new click-handler to the button. The click-handler should only be added once.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
       var lastSerial;
       var source = new EventSource("script.php");
           source.onmessage = function(event){
               lastSerial = event.lastEventId;
               document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "New transaction: " + event.data + "<br>";
      }; // end on.message
       $("#start").click(function(){
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: 'script.php',
               data: {lastSerial: lastSerial},
               success: function(data){
                   console.log(data);
               }
           });
       });
});
</script>
<button id="start"> start</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @Björn Tantau that sounds right. But where did my line `var lastSerial = event.lastEventId;` go to? That's what I need to pass as `data` in my ajax call.

Comment: See my edit. I added it as a global variable. Though you may consider adding it in a closure.

Comment: Actually, I'll add the closure right away, as the click-handler currently can't be bound to the button because it is added after the script.